# Cannot connect to local XMPP server using aSmack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am trying connect to a local XMPP server (Vysper) from an Android App using this code:

```
// ...
ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.1.107", 5222);

// load file from "Pictures" directory from Internal Memory
File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
file.mkdirs();
connectionConfig.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", file + "/clientkeystore");

Log.i("Info", file.getAbsolutePath());

XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connectionConfig);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);

connection.connect();
//...
```

This is the stack trace:

```
01-27 20:41:07.489 3229-3229/ E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bm.sam, PID: 3229
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
at com.bm.sam.LoginActivity.onClickLoginButton(LoginActivity.java:187)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using aSmack 4.0.6 and the Android API 19.

Android network permissions and file permissions have been granted:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log says you have a Log.e that is empty, so check that Log first:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
```